# Trying to import large sql file in MySQL fails

Tags: mysql, php, import

I am trying to import an SQL file that is 685MB into MySQL.

First I tried it through `phpmyadmin` - it failed.

Then I tried through the command line with:

```
mysql -u root -p database-name < file.sql
```

but it fails after importing ~500MB sometimes more sometimes less, it is different.

then I tried using a `PHP` script which I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883079/best-practice-import-mysql-file-in-php-split-queries) accepted answer. But it again fails after importing ~500MB. I tried getting the exact error with this:

```
function mysql_exec_query($query) 
{
    global $mysqli;

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

but it did not output the error and there is nothing in `MySQL` logs.

Also, I tried running the query immediately after the last successful query and it run successfully.

My PHP memory and other limits are set to `1G`.

Also, I've set some mysql config settings in my `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
general_log=1
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/general-query.log
```

but nothing helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Load CLI (`mysql -u root -p`) then load your dump file with `USE database-name; SOURCE file.sql` command and look for diagnostic/error message.

Comment: How much RAM in the machine?  "Failed" == stopped quietly?  said something?  crashed the server?  what?  Also, how long did it run before "failing"?

Comment: general_log=1 is not a good practise. "mysql -u root -p database-name < file.sql " what's the ouput in errorlog?